# Batch script not running

Tags: windows, batch-file, architecture, batch-processing

can you help me please?

This piece of script is not running and i can't figure why.

```
@echo off
ver | findstr /i "5\.1\."
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    set os_ver="xp"
)

ver | findstr /i "6\.1\." > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    set os_ver="7"
)

if %os_ver% == "xp" (
    set os_bits="32"
)

if %os_ver% == "7" (
    if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == "x86" (
        set os_bits="32"
    ) else (
        set os_bits="64"
    )
    echo %os_bits%
)
pause
```

it doesn't echo anything despite "ECHO IS DEACTIVATED" or "ECHO IS ACTIVATED"

update:
I posted the entire code, beacause people are saying that it is working

Update2:
I'm on a Windows 7 64 bits

Comment: Works for me. I see nothing wrong with your batch code, other than you should have "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" but that isn't affecting the functionality.

Comment: I've updated with the entire code.

Comment: "ECHO IS DEACTIVATED"? Are you translating? If so, the English version of the message is "ECHO is off".

Comment: Yes, I'm translating, sorry. My Windows is in Brazilian Portuguese. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch script appears to work fine. It will not echo if your machine is not Windows 7 though.

Try the following:

```
@echo off

set os_ver="unknown!"
set os_bits="unknown!"

ver | findstr "5\.1" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    set os_ver="xp"
)

ver | findstr "6\.1" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    set os_ver="7"
)

if %os_ver% == "xp" (
    set os_bits="32"
)

if %os_ver% == "7" (
    if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == "x86" (
        set os_bits="32"
    ) else (
        set os_bits="64"
    )
)

echo os_ver = %os_ver%
echo os_bits = %os_bits%

pause
```

Update: commenter eryksun has provided the correct reason why this code works while the ops does not even though he is on Windows7. (Good catch)

> In the OP's version echo %os_bits% is executed within the same command that sets os_bits. At the time the command is parsed and dispatched os_bits doesn't exist (unless it was already set), so it's just executing echo, which prints whether echo is on or off. – eryksun

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks!! But i wanted to know why it was not working before. What I was missing?

Comment: the placement of the echo command, was only executed inside of the check for windows 7. I made some other minor edits to your code as well for good-practice but they didn't affect anything. eg, removed /i switches for findstr (not need if you are comparing numbers, case-senstive is more efficient), and added > nul for the xp ver check so it won't echo in case it detects xp.

Comment: @Rafael Please confirm what your windows version is for other readers so I can update the answer with more details to help describe why this works. I assume you are not on windows 7.

Comment: I was echoing inside the check of win7 for debugging purposes. I don't want to echo it, it's just the beginning of the script i'm trying to make (and I already got lost xD)

Comment: I'm on a windows 7 64 bits, that's why i'm not understanding why the code was not running. But yours ran perfectly.

Comment: @Rafael Then, we need to figure out why it works for me and not you. Please type ver in a command window and paste your version string here. Also the value of %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%.

Comment: mine ver is Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]. architecture is AMD64

Comment: In the OP's version `echo %os_bits%` is executed within the same command that sets `os_bits`. At the time the command is parsed and dispatched `os_bits` doesn't exist (unless it was already set), so it's just executing `echo`, which prints whether echo is on or off.

Comment: So I can't set a variable and use it inside the same if?

Comment: Oh, just for curiosity, what does "OP" mean?

Comment: OP stands for "Original Poster"

Comment: No you cannot set a variable and use it inside the same if statement.  If I remember, there is a way you can sort of do it but things get even stranger then. It's beyond my knowledge of BATCH. It's much easier just to remember that you cant set a variable and also use it inside the same if statement. :)

Comment: @Rafael, you can set and reference a *local* variable if you use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then reference it as `!os_bits!`, but the value doesn't persist after `endlocal`, or the end of the batch script.

Comment: @Rafael, if you want delayed expansion to be enabled by default, set the registry `REG_DWORD` value `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DelayedExpansion` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" equ "x86" (
    set os_bits="32"
) else (
    set os_bits="64"
)
echo %os_bits%
```

Comment: equ is meant for comparing numbers, == is meant for comparing strings